# R xts loses timezone attribute

Tags: r, xts

I have just faced what I find a very weird behavior with xts objects. If I use a comparison operator on an xts object, it loses its timezone attribute. I have not encountered such an outcome with any other operator.

```
> a=matrix(seq(1,4),ncol=2,nrow=2)
> a=xts(a, order.by=as.POSIXct(seq(1,2), origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT"))
> a
                    [,1] [,2]
1970-01-01 00:00:01    1    3
1970-01-01 00:00:02    2    4
Warning message:
timezone of object (GMT) is different than current timezone (). 


> a>0
                    [,1] [,2]
1970-01-01 01:00:01 TRUE TRUE
1970-01-01 01:00:02 TRUE TRUE
```

Is this an expected behavior or a bug in the xts implementation?

Comment: `sessionInfo()` to check which version of  `xts`

Comment: Welcome to SO! I can confirm this with `xts_0.9-7` and `R 3.2.0`, win7.

Comment: But it works with `xts_0.9.874`. That is why `sessionInfo()` is useful.

Comment: I WAS using cran package with xts_0.9-7. Now obviously relying on github. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Development for [xts has moved to GitHub](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts). This is bug #2750 and was fixed in [revision 790](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/commit/a4e4f762eb18a310f281328d5be23efb9dc7c99f) on R-Forge ([issue #10 on GitHub](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/10)). xts 0.9-8 is scheduled to go to CRAN by the end of this week.

Answer (score 1):

Update - the `xts` package: `install.packages("xts", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")` or from [link](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=118)

```
> a>0
                    [,1] [,2]
1970-01-01 00:00:01 TRUE TRUE
1970-01-01 00:00:02 TRUE TRUE
Warning message:
timezone of object (GMT) is different than current timezone (). 

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)


other attached packages:
[1] xts_0.9.874 zoo_1.7-10 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.1.2      lattice_0.20-29 tools_3.1.2
```